# Sum values of input fields with same name and display them individually

Tags: javascript

I have the below input fields of a processed order form in which:

1. Order date is given on the **name** field as array
2. Cost is given on the **value** field

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="09-15-2017[]" id="dateprice[]" value="1">
   <input type="hidden" name="09-13-2017[]" id="dateprice[]" value="3">
   <input type="hidden" name="09-13-2017[]" id="dateprice[]" value="4">
   <input type="hidden" name="09-15-2017[]" id="dateprice[]" value="5">
   ```

The output im trying to get as an alert is:

```
Total amount on 09-13-2017 is 7
Total amount on 09-15-2017 is 6
```

This what im currently trying:

```
var chkprice = 0;        
var chkdate = 0;        

var inps = document.getElementsByID('dateprice[]');
for (var i = 0; i <inps.length; i++)
{
  var inp=inps[i];
  var chkprice = inp.value;

  if(chkdate==chkdate)
  {
    chkprice +=chkprice;                
  }
  alert("Total amount on "+chkdate+""+chkprice);
  alert(chkprice);
}
```

I know i have done a terrible javascript scripting.
Can any one guide me in getting values as shown above?

Comment: Don't use `id` here. `Id` must be unique. Use `class` in this case.

Comment: That's why there is no `getElementsByID`, not plural, it is `getElementByID`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/399/)**.

First of all the `id` attribute should be unique in the same document so you could use the common classes instead like :

```
<input type="hidden" name="09-15-2017[]" class="dateprice" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="09-13-2017[]" class="dateprice" value="3">
<input type="hidden" name="09-13-2017[]" class="dateprice" value="4">
<input type="hidden" name="09-15-2017[]" class="dateprice" value="5">
```

Then you could use an object to store the some using the name of inputs as key like :

```
var inps = document.querySelectorAll('.dateprice');
var totals = {};

//Sum calculation
for (var i = 0; i <inps.length; i++)
{
  totals[inps[i].name] = (totals[inps[i].name] || 0) + Number(inps[i].value);
}

//Result display
for (var key in totals) {
  if (totals.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log("Total amount on " + key + " is " + totals[key]);
  }
}
```

**NOTE :** You coudle remove the brackets **[ ]** from the output using `replace()` like :

```
console.log("Total amount on " + key.replace('[]','') + " is " + totals[key]);
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var inps = document.querySelectorAll('.dateprice');
var totals = {};

//Sum calculation
for (var i = 0; i <inps.length; i++)
{
  totals[inps[i].name] = (totals[inps[i].name] || 0) + Number(inps[i].value);
}

//Result display
for (var key in totals) {
  if (totals.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log("Total amount on " + key + " is " + totals[key]);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="09-15-2017[]" class="dateprice" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="09-13-2017[]" class="dateprice" value="3">
<input type="hidden" name="09-13-2017[]" class="dateprice" value="4">
<input type="hidden" name="09-15-2017[]" class="dateprice" value="5">
```